# How to print response headers to console and save content to file?

Tags: httpie

How can I print the response headers to console and save the response content to a file?

---

I  tried

```
http GET http://download.sysinternals.com/files/SysinternalsSuite.zip --output sis.zip
```

But this printed both the headers and content to the file, making it nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. Reported issue https://github.com/jkbr/httpie/issues/97

**Update 2013**: Fixed. Try

```
http -h --download http://download.sysinternals.com/files/SysinternalsSuite.zip
```

Answer (score 6):

It is possible in an updated version, the `--output` option will print the output into a file, and the `--download` option will make sure that the headers are print to the console, and only the content to the output file.

Here is an example:

```
http GET "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Stack%20Overflow" --download --output bla.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what HTTPie does *by default*:

- [When the output is not redirected](https://github.com/jkbr/httpie#terminal-output), the **whole message** is printed to the terminal (headers & body). However, **binary data is not printed** to the terminal.
- [When the output is redirected to a file](https://github.com/jkbr/httpie#redirected-output), then **only the body** is printed (headers & body). It doesn't matter whether the body is binary or not.

So, the output depends on where it is being printed to. You can overwrite the default context-sensitive behaviour with one of the [output options](https://github.com/jkbr/httpie#output-options). For example, the following saves the headers as well as the body to a file:

```
http --output sis.zip --print=hb download.sysinternals.com/files/SysinternalsSuite.zip
```

HTTPie currently doesn't allow outputing binary data to the terminal.